# How can I add new Formats in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.0. After recording my tests in Selenium IDE, I am able to export code into Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver format. There is no option to convert into Java / TestNG / WebDriver.

I like to add Java / TestNG / WebDriver format in Selenium IDE. Is it possible? If yes, what's the way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a plug in or google to see if one exists:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5492